# ckeditor - not able to type or click contents of textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, cfml, ckeditor4.x

I'm using Coldfusion 9 and CKeditor 4.5.3.  I'm replacing the cftextarea tag with textarea.  I simply added ;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/control/promos_new/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and added class="ckeditor" to the textarea;

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="50" id="jobad" name="jobad" rows="10"><cfoutput>#jobInfo.jobad#</cfoutput></textarea>
```

I get the textarea with toolbars but cannot click or type in the content.  The only thing I see in Firebug console is;
NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: but I get that error when using cftextarea.  On the same site in another page ckeditor works just fine.  There may be a problem interacting with Jquery 1.11

Comment: How are you initializing CKEditor?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the editor initialization

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/control/promos_new/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<script>
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('jobad');
</script>
```

Comment: It's funny that I had that code originally,  but following another page on our site that uses ckeditor without the script,  I removed it.  Now that I've put it back in,  I get the content and can edit it but it's not rendering the html in the content and there is no toolbar.  I get a console error :ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined.

Comment: I can't run Coldfusion on JSfiddle.  Besides,  I have a page where ckeditor works.  It doesn't have Jquery on it.  The page I'm having trouble with does.  There might be a conflict somewhere.

Comment: I had commented out the ckeditor js.  Now that it's back in I get the textarea with a toolbar but no content and I can't type anything. I also get a console error: uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.editor] The instance "jobad" already exists.

Comment: *can't run Coldfusion on JSfiddle* Yes, but it does not look like you need CF code to reproduce the error.  Since javascript has a much wider audience, you will increase the odds of getting an answer if you can remove CF from the equation entirely. Create a small, stand-alone, example using JS/CKEditor only.